# Discrete set of critical points of a holomorphic map.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $U$ be an open domain in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. Let $m\ge n$ and let $F:U\to C^{m}$ be a holomorphic map.

> What are the sufficient conditions for $F$ to have a discrete set of critical points?

One can show that if $F$ is an injection, then the set of critical points is thin, and so if $n=1$, this is sufficient. I am interested in a general case.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you come up with sufficient conditions?

Comment: no, found a way to solve my problem without that

Answer (score 0):

The set of critical points is the set where the derivative $Df_p \colon T_p {\mathbb C}^n \to T_{f(p)}{\mathbb C}^m$ is not of maximum rank (i.e. $Df_p$ is the Jacobian matrix).  So the trick is to look at the variety described by the $m \times m$ or $n \times n$ subdeterminants of $Df_p$.  So if $m=n$, then the set of critical points is either empty or a hypersurface as there is only one function.  In other words, if $m=n$ and there are critical points, they are discrete only if $m=n=1$.  If $m < n$, the there always at least $n$ possible $m \times m$ subdeterminants, so generically the set of critical points will be discrete.  If $m > n$, then there are always at least $m$ possible $n \times n$ subdeterminants, and $m > n$, so again generically the set of critical points will be discrete.

To check, I assume you generally have to compute the Jacobian matrix and those particular determinants.  The $n=1$ case is simple because a zero set of a holomorphic function is either everything, discrete, or empty.

An example in $n=2$, $m=3$, where the mapping is 1-1, but the set of critical points is not discrete is for example $(z,w) \mapsto (z^2,z^3,w)$.  The Jacobian matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2z & 0 \\
3z & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The three subdeterminants are $0$, $2z$, and $3z$, so their common zero set is $z=0$, which happens to be a hypersurface.

If on the other hand we perturb the thing very slightly to $(z,w) \mapsto (z^2+\epsilon zw,z^3,w)$, we find the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2z + \epsilon w & \epsilon z \\
3z & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the three subdeterminants are $3 \epsilon z^2$, $2z+\epsilon w$, and $3z$.  Their common zero set is $z=w=0$, a discrete set.

Comment: Well, the point of my question was, what kind of condition would be sufficient for the intersection of the zerosets of the subdeterminants to be discrete? You say that generically this has to be the case, but I need to get rid of the non-generic cases somehow. I undersand that one can look on the gradients of these subdeterminants and require them to span $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, but this will be a terrible mess. So I hoped that there might be a simpler geometrical (global?) condition on $F$, that would imply that. I understand that injectivity does not work, but perhaps something else does?